# Copy selected text to Clip Board on Pressing ALT Key: C#

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-shortcuts

Facing an issue while copying text to Clipboard on pressing ALT + 8(any numeric) key on keyboard .
While it is Working fine with CTRL + 8(any numeric)

Tried the following code:

```
Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
        ModifierKeys modifier = (ModifierKeys)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);

       // Keys key1 = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
       // ModifierKeys modifier1 = (ModifierKeys)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);

        if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            //System.UInt32 Modif = (((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
            //  System.UInt32 Key = ShiftRight(((int)(m.LParam)), 16);
            //     if ((((int)Key1 == VK_b)
            //         && ((int)modifier1 == MOD_CONTROL)))
                 {
             // Check foregroundwindow has a valid handle   
                         if (((System.IntPtr)GetForegroundWindow() != IntPtr.Zero))
                         {
                 // Send the Ctrl+C command to the active window   
                 SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
             }
         }
```

Comment: You probably need to send on detecting key release, with a delay, otherwise it will be like pressing ALT + 8 + CTRL + C at the same time.